# i want to add front and rear camera in one activity it is possible

Tags: android, android-camera

i am create a android application where i want to add front and rear camera in same activity and record the vedio and send to server  i am new and i don't know it is possible or not please help me if it is possible please guide me

i am seen this app [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wik.dualcamera&hl=en) and this also [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.behind.the.camera&hl=en)

**this sample code**

```
public class TestDualCam extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private Button record_frontCam, record_rearCam;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
int cameraType = 1;
private SurfaceView frontSurface, rearSurface;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private boolean recording;
Camera camera;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    recording = false;
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    init();
    initMediaRecorder();
    initfrontMeadiaRecorder();
    surfaceHolder = rearSurface.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder = frontSurface.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    record_rearCam.setOnClickListener(this);
    record_frontCam.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void init(){
    record_frontCam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.record1);
    record_rearCam =(Button)findViewById(R.id.record2);
    frontSurface =(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaced1);
    rearSurface =(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaced2);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.record1:
            Toast.makeText(TestDualCam.this, "Front Camera Open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(recording){
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                finish();
            }else{
                mediaRecorder.start();
                recording = true;
                record_frontCam.setText("STOP");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.record2:
            Toast.makeText(TestDualCam.this, "Rear Camera Open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(recording){
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                finish();
            }else{
                mediaRecorder.start();
                recording = true;
                record_rearCam.setText("STOP");
            }
            break;

    }


}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    prepareMediaRecorder();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
private void initMediaRecorder(){
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo1.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000); // Set max duration 30 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
}

private void prepareMediaRecorder(){
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void initfrontMeadiaRecorder(){
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ =        CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo1.mp4");
mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000); // Set max duration 30 sec.
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000);

  }
}
```

Comment: could you share some codes plz?

Comment: @MohammadZarei see this code